# Tibco EMS between different applications

Tags: java, spring, tibco-ems, ems, tibco-topic

Is it possible to send a class object between two different applications using Tibco EMS topic. Should the class be created at receiver end also for the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes TIBCO EMS can handle message of type 'Object' that are Java objects.

Link to the online documentation below :
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.6.0/doc/html/GUID-C7E6CD95-C172-4755-BDF0-63DCC944F6D0.html